# Why is the block size so big, taking into account a relatively small number of transactions?

Tags: segregated-witness, blocksize, block-weight

Why the size of the block [656143](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/656143) is so big (`Size`: **2,337,727** bytes), taking into account a relatively small number of transactions (`Number of Transactions`: **84**)?

**Extra question**: What is the block size limit in Bitcoin nowadays?
I found some guidelines [here](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/what-is-bitcoin/what-is-the-bitcoin-block-size-limit):

> Bitcoin blocks now have a theoretical maximum size of 4 megabytes and a more realistic maximum size of 2 megabytes.

However, the size of the block [656143](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/656143) is ~2.3Mb; therefore, a "more realistic maximum" is not that realistic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the size of the block 656143 is so big (Size: 2,337,727 bytes), taking into account a relatively small number of transactions (Number of Transactions: 84)?

It contains a number of transactions which are substantially larger than average (it is spending a very large number of outputs, legacy P2SH multisig scripts), so an assumption based on the average size of transactions does not hold.

[image: duh?]

> However, the size of the block 656143 is ~2.3Mb; therefore, a "more realistic maximum" is not that realistic :)

The quote refers to the assumed average size, not including obvious outliers like this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "inputs" instead of outputs in a "very large number of outputs"?

Comment: Possibly! The nomenclature in Bitcoin is always a little strained, in this case the transaction is spending a large number of outputs (UTXO entries), which are the inputs to the transaction I showed in the screenshot.